# Unconfirmed incoming transaction for a long time

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I received BC from currency exchange provider. Is unconfirmed for a pretty long time. Is this standard waiting time or maybe sender did not provide enough fee? I didn't have any choice what fee he payed and I think it is not possible to pay it after the transaction...
Thanks for the input.

https://blockchain.info/address/19oaganA4BN4khDn1kno6mctxLKSmFadk4

Comment: The transaction was confirmed, 5 minutes after you posed the question.

Answer (score 0):

The fees are quite low indeed. If you check the [transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/04f60bb45815271c4f39e4715de21e33dd0215f45940033ff0c4027f4f8fb238) instead of the address, you can notice that they are paying 51 Satoshi/Byte.

According to [bitcoinfees.21.co](https://bitcoinfees.21.co/), the recommended rate to get a transaction confirmed as soon as possible is around 220 Satoshi/byte nowadays.

So, what you can do is either wait until the transaction get confirmed, or spend the `UTXO` by creating a new transaction with a high fee, following a **Child-pays-for-Parent** [(CPFP)](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/4odi90/can_someone_explain_cpfp_child_pays_for_parent/) approach.

Comment: Thank You for the hint. Can I do CPFP trick sending money to different address of the same wallet or it must be another wallet?

Comment: You can do it using the same wallet (even the same address if you want). Just make sure that the fee is big enough. (Since that fee will pay for both transactions, try to set it a little bigger than the 220 Sat/byte, just in case).

Comment: The value of transaction (not the fee) makes any difference? I just have an option of 0.002004 BTC/KiB as the maximum fee in my wallet.

Comment: Well I guess it could could bound the maximum fee you could pay, if the fee is extracted from the UTXO you want to spend. On the other hand, if you are not extracting it from the current UTXO but from other funds you have within the same wallet, it could be bound by how many bitcoins you can spend.

Comment: By the way, it seems that the trick worked, you have both transactions confirmed.